# After localization: Unable to find nib named ... in bundle path: (null)

Tags: macos, xcode4, localization, xib

I'm starting to get into Mac OS X development and I have a problem the solution to which I haven't been able to figure out for the last three hours (I've googled a long time).

**Test application:**
I have an application that has a `MainMenu.xib`, which displays a window - so far so good. I've created another XIB and `NSViewController` subclass that contains a view which I want to display within the main window. I use the following code to load the view and insert it into the main window:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.compartmentViewController = [[SelectCompartmentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectCompartmentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.compartmentViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
    [self.compartmentViewController.view setFrame:[self.contentArea bounds]];              
}
```

`compartmentViewController` is a property and `self.contentArea` is a custom view on the main window - like a placeholder.

This works fine so far.

**Problem**
Then I decided to check out the localization feature. I've localized a couple of strings and both XIBs. At first I was a bit confused by not seeing any localized values. That was until I found out I had to clean the project - since then I've been getting the following error when running:

> 2013-03-19 22:48:59.763 Vocab Box[10160:303] unable to find nib named: SelectCompartmentViewController in bundle path: (null)
>   2013-03-19 22:48:59.764 Vocab Box[10160:303] -[NSViewController loadView] could not load the "SelectCompartmentViewController" nib.

**Suggested solutions I've tried to no avail**

1. Cleaning the project doesn't help
2. Checking the build configuration - yes, the bundle resources seem to be ok
3. Yes, if I remove the localization for my subview and re-add the original XIB, things are fine again (though of course the view is not localized)

*Help*

Answer (score 7):

I don't have an answer as to why this happens. But I had the same problem, and I fixed it by closing xCode and opening it up again, believe me.

Comment: I've rebooted the Mac for many consecutive days, restarting XCode as well. And it didn't work - believe me.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this. When I started creating and removing localizations from the project at some point I completely messed up my project configuration. That was when I decided to start over, got the last version of my project cloned from git and tried this: I created a localization, then localized just one xib, cleaned the project, removed the app, and it did not work. I rebooted xCode, and it worked... o.O

Comment: I can not remove an app - I'm developing a desktop application.

Comment: It just happened to me again. As I went on to localize another xib, the error came up again saying the nib was not found. At that moment I closed xCode and opened it again, built and ran the project again and it was working...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

- select your project
- select "build phases"
- add the new xib in the "copy bundle resources"

[image]

Comment: It actually appears in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and was able to solve it by doing the following:

1) Select the XIB in the project navigator

2) In the File Inspector, uncheck any items under Localization (it will prompt you - make sure 'delete files from disk' is unchecked, and press Remove)

3) Manually add the XIB back into the project

Comment: I already tried this. I completely removed all localizations and it didn't help.